# How can use slug for all urls in django without anything before or after?

Tags: django, django-urls

I want all djaango urls use slug field without any parameter before or after, by default
just one url can use this metod

Views.py

```
class ArticleDetail(DetailView):
    def get_object(self):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        article = get_object_or_404(Article.objects.published(), slug=slug)

        ip_address = self.request.user.ip_address
        if ip_address not in article.hits.all():
            article.hits.add(ip_address)

        return article

class CategoryList(ListView):
    paginate_by = 5
    template_name = 'blog/category_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        global category
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        category = get_object_or_404(Category.objects.active(), slug=slug)
        return category.articles.published()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['category'] = category
        return context
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name="detail"),
    path('<slug:slug>', CategoryList.as_view(), name="category"),
]
```

This is my django blog codes,
I don't want write article or category & ... in urls, just slug

mysite .com/article-slug
...
mysite .com/category-slug

Comment: It will always trigger the `Article` view, regardless if there is an `Article` for that slug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django multiple slug urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66929444/django-multiple-slug-urls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@WillemVanOlsem is right, you will have to write a view like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound

def slug_router(request, slug):
    if Category.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists():
        return CategoryList.as_view()(request, slug=slug)
    elif Article.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists():
        return ArticleDetail.as_view()(request, slug=slug)
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('404 Page not found')
```

And then

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>', slug_router, name="slug"),
]
```

... if I'm not mistaken. This should be the jist of it.
I didn't test this code, just typed it in here, so let me know if it doesn't work, I'll help to fix it.

Note that you'll have a preference if there are Articles with the same slug as some Categories.

Comment: Hi @barney-szabolcs
I can only say woooow, it works very well I worked it hard for several days, but I did'nt get any results. you and WillemVanOlsem are my angel of salvation. Thank you very much❤️

Comment: Hi @SaraNancy it is so nice of you to write us that we could help! ❤️ Best of luck in the future! 

Answer (score 3):

It will always trigger the `Article` view, regardless if there is an `Article` for that slug. You thus should make the URL patterns non-overlapping such that the other views can be triggered, for example with:

```
path('article/<slug:slug>/', Article.as_View(), name="articledetail"),
path('category/<slug:slug>/', Category.as_View(), name="category"),
path('product/<slug:slug>/', Product.as_View(), name="productdetail"),
```

If you want a path that accepts a single slug, you should define a view that looks if there is an `Article` with that slug, if that is not the case a `Category` and if that is not the case a `Product` you thus implement that logic in the view, not in the URL patterns.

Comment: No I want urls like this: mysite .com/articleslug

Comment: @SaraNancy: then you need to make a single complicated view that first looks if there is an article with that slug, if that fails a category, and if that fails the product, so a single view.

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOlsem, Thank you very much ❤️